# save firefox webpage by xdotool

Tags: xdotool

1. I want to save a firefox webpage using xdotool, and rename the saved
   file to be `test`.

   ```
   $ xdotool search "<FirefoxWindowName>" windowactivate --sync  \
   key ctrl+s  type  'test'  --sync  key alt+s
   ```

   But the rename isn't current, and may include part of `--sync  key
   alt+s` as the new name. Also `alt+s` isn't performed.
2. I also hope to choose
       "Webpage, complete", and possibly change saving destinationHow
       shall I do these by xdotool?

   Thanks.

Comment: Instead of alt+s you can also use "enter"

Comment: @Tim: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...

Comment: @Fabby;  I appreciated the answer,  so clicked the little up-arrow. I am still open to other answers, so I left the checkmark unchecked.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little script for that.

*Probably you still need to adjust the window names.*

```
#!/bin/bash

# Firefox win id
FFWID=$(xdotool search --name "Google - Mozilla Firefox" | head -n1)

xdotool windowactivate "$FFWID" --sync

# Safe dialog win id
FFDWID=$(xdotool search --name "Save as" --sync)

xdotool windowactivate "$FFDWID"
xdotool key "ctrl+s" type "save"
xdotool key "alt+s"
```